# What do you need to watch out for when using cross-validation with GLM lambda search?

Tags: glm, cross-validation, h2o

Regarding [h2o.glm lambda search not appearing to iterate over all lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45890985/841830), I read the question as complaining that lambda was too high;  they tried setting `early_stopping=F` in the hope that might fix that "bug".

Isn't it the case that the original behaviour was a feature, not a bug? And if that is correct, then you should always use `early_stopping=T` when using cross-validation with GLM, otherwise the error estimate from cross-validation is useless; you also risk over-fitting.

(My main question is if my understanding of the way GLM and CV work together is correct; but I'd be interested if there are any other things to watch out for when using lambda_search and cross-validation together.)

Answer (score 1):

H2O's glm with lambda search and cross-validation should always pick the best lambda based on cross-validation and use that in the returned (main) model. The early stopping option should have no effect on selected lambda. Its purpose is to skip computation of models for lambdas > best since they are not needed for the main model (we still compute models for lambdas < best since that allows to use warm starting and take full advantage of strong rules).

I think the behavior with early_stopping set to false should compute models for all lambdas in case user wants to see them / do custom model selection.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, that is interesting. In the linked to question, the best lambda of the 3 cv folds were 0.011, 0.018, 0.016, but the model's best lambda was 0.106 (i.e. 10 times larger). It doesn't look like it has been picked based on cross-validation, but is that still possible with some unusual data?  (Or is that also a symptom of the #4858 early stopping bug?)